# Can't upload to Azure Storage after deploy Koa app to Azure App Service

Tags: file-upload, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, koa, koa-bodyparser

When App run on local, I can upload file to Azure Blob Storage.

But when I deploy app to Azure App Service, it always responses 502 Bad Gateway

I use library `koa-body` to handle upload file

```
const koaBody = require('koa-body')({ multipart: true, uploadDir: '.' });
const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
const videoContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(AZURE_VIDEO_STORAGE_CONTAINER);
const blobVideoName = `${fileName}.${fileExtension}`;
const blockBlobVideo = videoContainerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobVideoName);
const uploadVid = blockBlobVideo.uploadFile(filePath);
```

I think the problem is I don't have permission to write file to `os.tmpDir()`, so I try to go to `Kudu Debug Console` and set `chmod -R 0755` to `home/site/wwwroot/public/tmp`, the folder I think is `os.tmpDir()`. But it said I don't have permission

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to my sample code.([Download my samle code](https://github.com/Jason446620/koa-upload))

[image]

[image]

**Test Result.**

POST test url  : `https://yourappname.azurewebsites.net/user/upload`

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see sidebar contain ```BLOB CONTAINERS```, ```FILE SHARES``` like in your image. Where did you click to get this ?

Comment: @KhiemNguyen On portal. https://i.imgur.com/q02BMBu.png

Comment: @KhiemNguyen You also can [download azure storage explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

Comment: OMG, I find out that the problem is I use ```fluent-ffmpeg``` to generate a thumbnail from video upload. After I remove it from code, I can upload correctly. Thank you for your supporting, I will create another post.